# flex mobile project : add zoom controls on google map

Tags: google-maps, flex4.5

I am developing a google map application using adobe flex 4.5 . I need to add zoom controls like one we see in android mobile(+,-) to the map. I am using  "map_flex_1_20.swc" file. If I use built in zoom controls it is appearing like one we see on desktop or web. please help me to add zoom controls(+,-) like on android device

Comment: hi prabhu see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964597/how-can-start-mobile-flex-google-map-application-using-adobe-flash-builder-4-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is possible in [JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call the function in your Event. I'll show you simple Code to doing this.
I hope this will help you.

```
protected function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void
            {


                    var lat:Number= 30.7500;
                    var long:Number= 76.7800;
                    map.addControl(new ZoomControl());
                    map.addControl(new PositionControl());
                    map.addControl(new MapTypeControl());
                    map.removeMapType(MapType.HYBRID_MAP_TYPE);


                    this.map.setCenter(new LatLng(lat,long), 12, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);

        }
```