# How can start mobile Flex Google Map application using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5?

Tags: google-maps, flash-builder4.5

I am new in Adobe Flex development. How can I start Google Map in mobile Flex application in Adobe Flex using Flash Builder 4.5?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow, which is why it attracted link-only answers at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also new to Adobe Flash and Flex development, but these links may help you

[Tutorial: Including Google Maps in an Adobe Flex application](http://www.andensolutions.com/index.php/blogs/tutorial-include-google-maps-in-an-adobe-flex-application/)

[Using Google Maps in a Flex project](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/03/using-google-maps-in-a-flex-project/)